# Can, could, or be able to in a B1 question

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, confusables

I was reading through an English B1 question paper, and came across this:

"I ____ drive as long as I take driving lessons" - Fill the gap with "can, "could", "be able to", or any of their negative forms.

Even though I have been speaking English as a second language for about 15 years and have lived in the UK for the last two, I have no clue what the answer is. I've read several articles trying to explain the differences but none seem to be relevant to this question. Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question is a little unclear: could we use any form of the suggestions as well as the negatives? (That said, I don't know how any negative form works unless you change the adverb to "until" or "unless".)

Comment: None of the options would be idiomatic in the US.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks that none of the options are idiomatic, but the third option, "I be able to drive ..." is worse than not idiomatic; it's just wrong.

Comment: @AndreasBlass "be able to" is its infinitive form, candidates *should be able to* conjugate it correctly.

Comment: Hugo Casañas Salgado can you copy word to word the actual instructions? And can you tell us if the question appears online or if it's printed in a book. If the latter, can you tell us its title, please.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The question doesn't say to conjugate the options to make the grammatically correct. It says to fill the blank with one of these or a negative form.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  and who's to say that the OP didn't copy word for word the test instructions? They wouldn't be the first nor the last.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the answer is "**could**" because we are dealing with a conditional in "as long as". Though many native speakers might say "**can**".

"**Can**" is probably allowable, depending on which grammar style or curriculum you consult. But, "**could**" is the "best" answer because it is most clear and uniquely fitting with the conditional. But, there is one more thing to consider in choosing "**could**"...

"**Could**" is used for conditionals that are once removed from our reality. With "**could**", either the condition is not yet met, can't be met, needs to be met only once, or something else of the sort. By contrast, **"can**" indicates an *ongoing* ability empowered by an *ongoing* condition being met. For example:

> I **can** drive early in the morning as long as I drink my coffee.

That would indicate an *ongoing* condition that is met every day the speaker drives.

But, "driving lessons" happen once, then are finished. Under normal circumstances, no one would need to continuously be enrolled in a driving school in order to be able to drive, neither in skill nor in law. The sentence doesn't indicate that these circumstances are not normal, so we should presume normal circumstances.

So, the one-event condition modal "**could**" should be the "best" answer.

---

(As a final note, we don't know what *[B1](https://www.britishcouncil.es/en/english/levels/b1)* is, unless you specify "MCERL B1" or "Aptis B1". But, it wouldn't change the answer for normal English, so I just overlooked that part of the question.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you so much! Is it limited to MCERL & Aptis?

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are wonderful!

Comment: I don't see how 'could' agrees with 'as long as I take'; I'd want 'I could drive as long as I took driving lessons'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I agree with you, and I also talk & write that way. But, I think some authorities find it acceptable to use either "take" or "took" with the Hypothetical/Conditional. I know for sure that we can say either "If I were you..." and "if I was you..." So, "could" does have problems, but "can" has more problems for the reasons I gave, making it the "best" answer, IMHO. But, I generally agree, at least with your preference. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

"Could" is a modal verb used to express possibility, because of the clause "as long as" the correct word here would be could

Answer (score 0):

Having a conditional clause "as long as I take driving lessons" doesn't necessarily make "could" any more desirable than "can". If anything, "can" is more congruent with the present tense "take" than "could" is.

The problem with "can" is not that somehow it cannot go with a conditional, but that its most obvious reading should be the general ability in the future in the given sentence, which sounds rather awkward.

> a. I **can** drive as long as I take driving lessons. [general ability in the future]

On the contrary, "could" can easily mean the remote possibility of a one-time event in the future:

> b. I **could** drive as long as I take driving lessons. [remote possibility in the future]

So if it's between "can" and "could" I would go with the latter.

That said, if adding 'will' is allowed, I'll definitely go with 'be able to' instead of "could", because it represents an permission to drive, which is the most fitting reading.

> c. I'll **be able to** drive as long as I take driving lessons.